# Where my file storage after deploy an app on google cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine

I write a simple nodejs that write files, but after deploy I found no place for that files.

I tried to SSH into the instance but nothing there.

Any idea

Comment: Not enough information to help you. Its not clear which product you are using as many people tag the wrong Google Cloud Platform product.